# Running wasp-cli locally

Tags: node, wasp, shimmerevm, docker

How to run wasp-cli locally using the official repo https://wiki.iota.org/shimmer/smart-contracts/guide/development_tools/docker_preconfigured/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instructions on how to run the docker compose should be clear. What is not clear there in the README of the repo is how to set up `wasp-cli`. If you take a look at the Makefile in the root of the gh repo, you'll see some commands that you can use. I went with `make build-cli`, which will generate an executable `wasp-cli` that you can run from the root of the folder.

Once you have that, you'll be able to call `./wasp-cli init`. That will create the config file `wasp-cli.json` in the same directory and there you can add the config specified in the docs, which is:

```
    {
      "l1": {
        "apiaddress": "http://localhost:14265",
        "faucetaddress": "http://localhost:8091"
      },
      "wasp": {
        "0": {
          "api": "127.0.0.1:9090",
          "nanomsg": "127.0.0.1:5550",
          "peering": "127.0.0.1:4000"
        }
      }
    }
```

Also `cp wasp-cli /usr/local/bin` can be used to be able to call it from anywhere.